# How can I know if SNMP Walk or a Table-View is started?

Tags: c, snmp, snmpwalk

Hello how can I know if a User has "sent" a SNMP-Walk or a TABLE-VIEW request to a device with UCD-SNMP/NET-SNMP and custom coding?